# How to write assert for the test class which includes ParseXML?

Tags: unit-test

```
static testMethod void testmet()
    {
      Rforce_BcsRbxParsing_Class bcpe=new Rforce_BcsRbxParsing_Class();
      List<Rforce_BcsRbxResponse_Class> bcsList=new List<Rforce_BcsRbxResponse_Class>();
      String formattedtext='<response><clientList><idClient>1-9805-35812</idClient><lastName>LAPORTE</lastName><lang>FRA</lang><firstName>ALAIN</firstName><BCScommAgreement><Global.Comm.Agreement/><Preferred.Communication.Method/><Post.Comm.Agreement/><Tel.Comm.Agreement/><SMS.Comm.Agreement/><Fax.Comm.Agreement/><Email.Comm.Agreement/></BCScommAgreement><contact/><address><strName>4 PASSAGE JOUFFROY</strName><countryCode>FR</countryCode><zip>75009</zip><city>PARIS</city></address><typeperson>P</typeperson></clientList><clientList><idClient>1-98EM-37711</idClient><lastName>LAPORTE</lastName><title>1</title><lang>FRA</lang><firstName>HENRI</firstName><BCScommAgreement><Global.Comm.Agreement/><Preferred.Communication.Method/><Post.Comm.Agreement/><Tel.Comm.Agreement/><SMS.Comm.Agreement/><Fax.Comm.Agreement/><Email.Comm.Agreement/></BCScommAgreement><contact><phoneNum1>+330145781138</phoneNum1></contact><address><strName>65 RUE DE JAVEL</strName><countryCode>FR</countryCode><zip>75015</zip><city>PARIS</city></address><typeperson>P</typeperson></clientList><clientList><idClient>1-ACY6-12318</idClient><lastName>LAPORTE</lastName><title>1</title><lang>FRA</lang><firstName>JEAN MARC</firstName><BCScommAgreement><Global.Comm.Agreement/><Preferred.Communication.Method/><Post.Comm.Agreement/><Tel.Comm.Agreement/><SMS.Comm.Agreement/><Fax.Comm.Agreement/><Email.Comm.Agreement/></BCScommAgreement><contact><phoneNum1>+330142723266</phoneNum1></contact><address><strName>36  rue du Temple</strName><countryCode>FR</countryCode><zip>75004</zip><city>PARIS</city></address><typeperson>P</typeperson></clientList><clientList><idClient>1-ACWC-32847</idClient><lastName>LAPORTE</lastName><title>1</title><lang>FRA</lang><firstName>PHILIPPE</firstName><BCScommAgreement><Global.Comm.Agreement/><Preferred.Communication.Method/><Post.Comm.Agreement/><Tel.Comm.Agreement/><SMS.Comm.Agreement/><Fax.Comm.Agreement/><Email.Comm.Agreement/></BCScommAgreement><contact><phoneNum1>+330142801966</phoneNum1><phoneNum2>+330611117959</phoneNum2></contact><address><strName>2 rue de Londres</strName><countryCode>FR</countryCode><zip>75009</zip><city>PARIS</city></address><typeperson>P</typeperson><vehicleList> <vin>VF7867687978897</vin></vehicleList></clientList><nbReplies>4</nbReplies></response>';
      bcsList=bcpe.parseXML(formattedtext);       
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cross check elements of list like:

```
System.assertEquals(bcsList.size()>0,true);
System.assertEquals(bcsList.size(),'SIZE_OF_LIST');
System.assertEquals(bcsList[0].idClient,'1-9805-35812');
```

Also put `bcsList=bcpe.parseXML(formattedtext);` statement in try-catch block.

Comment: Will you change the order to `assertEquals(expected, actual)` so the assertion failure messages make sense?